# Connecting Android emulator with Expo Cli: device 'adb' not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I'm trying to connect an Android emulator device that I created using Android studio to Expo CLI.
However, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Couldn't adb reverse: ** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon: Connection refused       
› Opening exp://10.0.0.22:19000 on Device adb
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: device 'adb' not found
```

A few things to mention:

- I do have SDK and platform-tools locations on my PATH.
- I do have a running Android emulator with developer mode.
- The adb is running

I couldn't find any useful solutions to my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What's expo cli?

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/

Answer (score 0):

This fixed for me when I go here:  https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

I followed the direction and set my environment within linux as this:

```
ANDROID_HOME="/your/path/to/androidSDK"

export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```